# importmagic ignores multiline settings

Tags: emacs

I have the following in my `emacs.d/init.el` :

```
(setq importmagic-configuration-style-alist '((multiline . backslash)
                                              (max_columns . 180000)))
```

And the following in my setup.cfg

```
[importmagic]
multiline = 'backslash'
max_columns = 1000
indent_with_tabs = 0
```

And when when I run `C-c C-l`, my imports change from:

```
import datetime
from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX import YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX import ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX import WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

to

```
import datetime
from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX import (,
    YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY)
from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX import ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX import (,
    WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW, AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA)
```

Which is invalid and actually breaks my code.

How can I make importmagic use backslash instead of parens as my settings clearly say to do?

What's worse is if you now do a /second/ import-magic run, they get chopped up completely:

```
import datetime
from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX import (,
from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX import ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ
from XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

`importmagic`'s README is wrong. [According to the source](https://github.com/anachronic/importmagic.el/blob/701dfcca5f3ab42be0f26a8d381d7116c79be850/importmagic.el) the the alist you want is `importmagic-style-configuration-alist`.

Comment: Maybe submit an issue so the maintainers can fix it.